# vue-multiselect not displaying array ( options: Array [0] )

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-multiselect

I am attempting to add a `vue-multiselect` into an existing form, however, the dropdown is empty. This is more than a display issue as Vue devtools shows me my array is empty. I get no issues in the console.

The value for my select is from my API, I'm 99% sure my code there works, as it's exactly the same as I use elsewhere in my app to display a loop of the same values.

I'm using Nux.js.

Following the docs and other questions on SO, I feel I'm pretty close with the below code, but something must be amiss, I just can't spot it.

**html**

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Gins</h1>
      <form @submit.stop.prevent="addGin">
        <h2>New Gin</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="gin_name" class="input-label">Title:</label>
            <input id="gin_name" v-model="gin_name" type="gin_name" name="gin_name" class="input">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="description" class="input-label">Description:</label>
            <input id="description" v-model="description" type="description" name="description" class="input">
        </p>
          <div>
            <label for="distillery" class="input-label">Distillery:</label>
            <multiselect
                v-model="distillery_id"
                track_by="id"
                :options="options"
                :searchable="true"
                placeholder="Choose One Distillery"
                >
            </multiselect>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {

  components: { Multiselect },
  data() {
    return {
      gin_name: '',
      description: '',
      distillery_id: '',
      options: []
    }
  },

  methods: {

    addGin() {
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/gins', {
        gin_name: this.gin_name, description: this.description
      })
        .then((response) => {})
    },
    getDistilleries() {
      axios.get('/api/v1/distilleries')
        .then((res) => {
          this.options = res.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: are you calling `getDistilleries` method some where?

Comment: No. Where would I call it? My form is calling the previous method `addGin`.

Comment: call it on `mounted` event like `mounted () { this.getDistilleries(); }`

Comment: okay that worked. Although I have the whole json string in the dropdown.

Comment: Solved that with:

   label(option) {
      return `${option.distillery_name}`
    },